# Background data ski areas

Tags: qgis, data

I'm trying to visualise a specific ski route. The sample is taken with a gps tracker in Obergurgl & Hochgurgl, Austria. I am using QGIS for this assignment. I could insert the trace using vector lines in QGIS.

But now I want to add some background data, like streets, heights, buildings for instance. Does anyone know how to do so or where to find the appropriate data?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can download Open Streetmap (OSM) data in QGIS using the ***OSMDownloader*** plugin (install it with the *Plugin Manager* - menu: *Plugins*-> *Manage and install plugins*). You can use the QuickOSM plugin to work with OSM data.

For background maps, the following QGIS plugins can be used:

- HCMGIS (various base maps)
- QuickMapServices (xyz tile services)

In the Browser panel you should also find *OpenStreetMap* under *XYZ Tiles*.